# Rails - create child record from parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Feel like an idiot for asking this, but I'm starting to feel like I learned it the wrong way originally.

I might note that I'm not using nested routes.

If I have two models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

What is the best way to create a new product from the appropriate parent category page?

At the moment I have this on the category page

```
<%= link_to new_product_path(:category_id => @category)
```

Then on the new product page Im using:

```
<%= form_for @product do |p| %>
  <%= p.hidden_field :category_id, :value => params[:category] %>
  #rest of fields
  #etc
<% end %>
```

This will work as long as the url parameter survives.  However, as soon as the user arrives on this page via the back button or the render 'new' as a result of failed validation, the url parameter is lost and this no longer works.

This is such a simple everyday rails task, there has to be a more reliable method of creating child records from the parent page.

Comment: you can try cookies to store the category value http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using nested routes?

Comment: Im not using nested routes because the categories have both sub-categories(self-join) and products.  This made it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your new and create actions to work similar to as if they were a nested category-product resources, by:

```
resources :products, except: [:new, :create] do
  get  :new, path: 'products/:category_id/new'
  post :create, path: 'products/:category_id'
end
```

You would still have to do:

```
<%= link_to new_product_path(:category_id => @category) %>
```

But you will not have to add the hidden fields in your form. Instead in your create action inside your controller you can do:

```
category = Category.find params[:category_id]
category.products.build(product_params)
```

Doing it this way you will not be utilizing url parameters, and failed validations should prompt you back to the proper page.

Answer (score 0):

All instance variables you define in your controller action are present in the view. So if you define `@category` in your controller you can access it in the view using `<%= @category %>`. This way you can avoid using `params` inside your view.

```
def new 
  @category = Category.find(params[:category])

def create
  @category = Category.find(params[:category])

<%= form_for @product do |p| %>
  <%= p.hidden_field :category_id, :value => @category.id %>
```